# Automapper, map Source to property of Destination

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map a (source) list of objects to a property of the destination object:

```
class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Destination
{
    public List<Source> ThingsWithNames { get; set; }
}
```

All the questions I have seen are about the other way around, but I want to "unflatten" my object here.

Comment: What is `SomeOtherStuff`?

Comment: Just other things I might have in my Destination object. Basically I am trying to map Entity Framework Objects to View Models, but next to my ThingsWithNames could be anything. The question is can I "defer" mapping to a property of the destination?

Comment: It's not clear about what you want. `Source` is your entity and `Destination` is your view model? And you want to map Source -> Destination?

Comment: Since your destination object doesn't need a projection of Source I don't see the need for mapping between Source and Destination. Maybe there's more of your example that you need to share.

Comment: Thank Jasen for having a look!

Sorry if it wasn't clear. I want to map a list of Source objects to the ThingsWithNames property of a destination object.

So if sourceList is a List<Source> I want to:
Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(sourceList) and get a Destination object back with ThingsWithNames set to the mapped List of source objects.

What I forgot was that the Source Mapping is one that I have already working. Also the automatic single object to List<> works fine. I just haven't figured out how to map it as a property of my destination object, instead of the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly...

What you are doing with

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(sourceList);
```

is really

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(IList<Source> sourceList);  // this is an error
```

You don't need AutoMapper for this. Instead it is just:

```
var destination = new Destination();
// or if you have another entity
var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(someotherEntity);

destination.ThingsWithNames = sourceList;
```

If your `someotherEntity` is a composite containing a List of `Source` then you define that mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SomeotherEntity, Destination>()
    .ForMember(d => d.ThingsWithNames, e => e.SourceList))
```

Now if you only care about the *Name* property of `Source` then define a mapping

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, string>().ConvertUsing(s => s.Name);
```

and that will automatically get you a `List<string>` if you need the collection

```
SomeOtherEntity
    List<Source> SourcesList { get; set; }

Destination
    List<string> ThingsWithNames { get; set; }

var destination = Mapper.Map<Destination>(someOtherEntity);
// now destination.ThingsWithNames is a List<string> containing your Source names
```

Comment: Thanks Jasen for taking your time! We're close :)

What I am trying to do is directly map into a viewmodel, which contains other properties.

So instead of mapping a => b, I want to map a => c.b, if that makes more sense. 

I tried your suggestions, as far as they pertained, but it's not quiet there yet. It seems I am overlooking something obvious and simple.

Comment: You will need to share a more concrete example to see what's hanging you up.